# glassfish and h2database problem

Tags: hibernate, spring, glassfish, jpa-2.0, h2

I build an java based app. using hibernate JPA, spring and h2database. I using h2database in memory mode, here is the jdbc properties:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc\:h2\:mem\:test_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY\=-1
jdbc.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=
```

This values I'm using in dataSource.xml like this:

```
<bean id="basicDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
```

I'm using two app context, first one:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.webtest">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"/>
</context:component-scan>
<import resource="basicDataSource.xml"/>
```

and the second one:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.webtest.persistence.dao.jpa"/>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="basicDataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

I loaded this two app. contexts in web.xml file like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
        classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext-persistence.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Finally here is my persistence.xml config:

```
<persistence-unit name="basicPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

But when I tried to deploy this jar to app container, a next error occured:

```
[#|2011-06-23T14:41:42.769+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:42.909+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|===== GUI deployment: needUploadToTempfile ======|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:42.925+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|======= uploadFileName=webFrontend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:42.928+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|===== filePath=/private/var/folders/m+/m+kO87fOGXS5o7r3iUMGR++++TI/-Tmp-/webFrontend-18640431189413583797.0-SNAPSHOT.war origPath=webFrontend-1|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:47.456+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:47.964+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:47.964+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:47.965+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:49.078+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:49.155+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:49.173+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:49.393+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool DerbyPool. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:49.398+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ DerbyPool ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:49.401+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.gjc.spi|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.]|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:49.740+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:49.745+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:49.758+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool DerbyPool. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:49.759+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ DerbyPool ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:49.760+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.gjc.spi|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.]|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:50.108+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC1412: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:50.109+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:50.278+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Jun 23 14:41:50 CEST 2011]; root of context hierarchy|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:50.483+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/webFrontend-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:50.747+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:50.750+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:50.892+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/webFrontend-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/basicDataSource.xml]|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:50.916+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/webFrontend-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-persistence.xml]|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:50.976+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:50.978+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:51.501+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Loading properties file from file [/opt/glassfish3/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/webFrontend-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/database.properties]|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:51.515+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:51.579+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@174faf5: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,basicDataSource,PersonDao,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAspect]; root of factory hierarchy|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:51.795+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'basicPersistenceUnit'|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:51.802+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:51.808+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:51.811+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:52.592+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:52.594+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:52.615+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@174faf5: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,basicDataSource,PersonDao,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAspect]; root of factory hierarchy|#]

[#|2011-06-23T14:41:52.657+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'PersonDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/webFrontend-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: basicPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4690)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5305)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:755)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1980)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1630)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:100)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.LocalDeploymentFacility$LocalDFCommandRunner.run(LocalDeploymentFacility.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.client.AbstractDeploymentFacility.deploy(AbstractDeploymentFacility.java:406)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.invokeDeploymentFacility(DeployUtil.java:100)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.deploy(DeployUtil.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.handlers.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.invokeCommandHandlers(CommandActionListener.java:150)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.processAction(CommandActionListener.java:98)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.component.WebuiCommand.broadcast(WebuiCommand.java:166)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:600)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/webFrontend-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: basicPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:529)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:495)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:629)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:338)
    ... 89 more
```

I noticed a warning at the begin of the log. There are something about refused connection to port 1527. My question is, must I configure a JDBC connection pool on glassfish to using in memory h2database, or the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: Where are you instantiating the h2database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your main problem is:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: basicPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
```

and looking at your persistence.xml, I think that you should try to insert the database configuration attributes inside it. I'm telling you this based on other experiences with JPA, but nothing related with Spring (as I saw at the other config files that you bond with the dataSource.)

Rapidly searching about it, I found that you have two ways to use Spring and JPA; and the more recommended is the one you starts to use "LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean", but without to pointing to the "dataSource", letting it to JPA using the "persistence.xml" file.

Look at this translated tutorial for more information: http://translate.google.com.br/translate?hl=en&sl=pt&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Ffabiolnm.blogspot.com%2F2009%2F11%2Fintegracao-spring-x-jpa.html

Comment: I tried run this configuration on tomcat and there works fine. Only what I changed was transaction-type from "JPA" to "LOCAL_RESOURCES" See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473808/persistence-transaction-type-value

Comment: OK @pierre-tautou . I've tried to answer your question there. But even if your problem with this question here was solved with the "JPA/RESOURCE_LOCAL" change, I recommend you to try the tutorial I liked, because it talks about good practices for JPA/SPRING integration. And please, if my answers were fine, vote up! =]

Answer (score 1):

I heard somewhere that Glassfish doesn't understand empty password in JDBC connection pool. In fact, using Tomcat solved your problem.