# Persistence transaction-type value?

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, glassfish, persistence

I have a question about persistence.xml config parameter "transaction-type". If I set this parameter to value "RESOURCE_LOCAL", than application run fine in tomcat application server. But not in glassfish. Glassfish gave me next error:

```
The persistence-context-ref-name [com.test.webtest.persistence.dao.jpa.AbstractGenericDaoJpa/entityManager] in module [webFrontend-1.0-SNAPSHOT] resolves to a persistence unit called [basicPersistenceUnit] which is of type RESOURCE_LOCAL. Only persistence units with transaction type JTA can be used as a container managed entity manager. Please verify your application.
java.lang.RuntimeException: The persistence-context-ref-name [com.test.webtest.persistence.dao.jpa.AbstractGenericDaoJpa/entityManager] in module [webFrontend-1.0-SNAPSHOT] resolves to a persistence unit called [basicPersistenceUnit] which is of type RESOURCE_LOCAL. Only persistence units with transaction type JTA can be used as a container managed entity manager. Please verify your application.
```

When I change the parameter to value "JTA", then glassfish gave me error again, but another:

```
[#|2011-06-24T18:46:48.955+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:49.185+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|===== GUI deployment: needUploadToTempfile ======|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:49.197+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|======= uploadFileName=webFrontend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:49.201+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|===== filePath=/private/var/folders/m+/m+kO87fOGXS5o7r3iUMGR++++TI/-Tmp-/webFrontend-17474491606051515474.0-SNAPSHOT.war origPath=webFrontend-1|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:54.765+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:55.672+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:55.672+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by |#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:55.672+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|log4j:ERROR [WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)] whereas object of type |#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:55.672+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|log4j:ERROR "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" was loaded by [WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)].|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:55.673+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "stdout".|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:56.980+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:57.403+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:57.409+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:57.773+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool DerbyPool. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:57.801+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ DerbyPool ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:57.831+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.gjc.spi|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.]|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:58.232+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:58.237+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:58.249+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool DerbyPool. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:58.250+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ DerbyPool ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:58.251+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.gjc.spi|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.]|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:58.257+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport).|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:58.257+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:58.257+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:46:58.727+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=88;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|PWC1412: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:47:00.642+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:47:00.648+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:47:00.651+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:47:01.277+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:47:01.279+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1|org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:47:01.336+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|PWC1306: Startup of context /webFrontend-1.0-SNAPSHOT failed due to previous errors|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:47:01.512+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|PWC1305: Exception during cleanup after start failed
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: PWC2769: Manager has not yet been started
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:5509)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:529)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5323)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:755)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1980)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1630)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:100)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.LocalDeploymentFacility$LocalDFCommandRunner.run(LocalDeploymentFacility.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.client.AbstractDeploymentFacility.deploy(AbstractDeploymentFacility.java:406)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.invokeDeploymentFacility(DeployUtil.java:100)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.deploy(DeployUtil.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.handlers.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.invokeCommandHandlers(CommandActionListener.java:150)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.processAction(CommandActionListener.java:98)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.component.WebuiCommand.broadcast(WebuiCommand.java:166)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:600)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
|#]

[#|2011-06-24T18:47:01.514+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'PersonDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/webFrontend-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: basicPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5328)
```

...

And tomcat gave me an error with "JTA" too:

```
ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'PersonDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.16/webapps/webFrontend-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: basicPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.16/webapps/webFrontend-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: basicPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:529)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:495)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:629)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:338)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: basicPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: The chosen transaction strategy requires access to the JTA TransactionManager
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:390)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:906)
    ... 39 more
```

So I would ask, for what is this parameter for? I read definition on Hibernate site: Transaction type must be "JTA" if is used in JavaEE enviroment. When GlassFish and Tomcat are JavaEE app containers, why when I'm using "RESOURCE_LOCAL" on Tomcat works all fine. And where do I mistake when parameter is "JTA" and both app containers gave me an error?

Answer (score 1):

From the official Oracle JTA technology site: *"Java Transaction API (JTA) specifies standard Java interfaces between a transaction manager and the parties involved in a distributed transaction system: the resource manager, the application server, and the transactional applications."* It means that when some software requirement involves more than one "atomic" action, you should group them inside a transaction so they all happen together or none of them happens. The famous example of bank accounts money transfer shows the transaction need (take $ from one and sum $ at the other are two atomic actions). For a Java EE environment the atomic action may involve a lot of different technologies that can be controlled using JTA via application servers.

Now answering your question: probably you are not using JTA... if you are using code like this,

```
this.manager = JPAUtility.getEntityManager();
this.manager.getTransaction().begin();
this.manager.persist(entidadeGenerica);
this.manager.getTransaction().commit();
this.manager.refresh(entidadeGenerica);
this.manager.close();
```

(probably in you DAO entities), means you are controlling the transactions yourself (**getTransation()**), and will not handle them via JTA. So you have to use "RESOURCE_LOCAL".

Finally, you are having problems using the "JTA" configuration, because it asks for more configurations and/or lines of code to work, mainly pointing which JTA's managers and rules should be used at specific cases.

PS.: Tomcat is not an app container because it implements only the web container specifications (basically Servlets and related)... Search Stackoverflow for this that you will confirm this.

Comment: I'm using spring annotation based transaction in my DAOs, so I must using "RESOURCE_LOCAL", am I right? But when I using this value, then glassfish gave me an error.